# react-virtualized: Table Column with CellMeasurer always has cache height

Tags: react-virtualized

I've been trying to follow the [DynamicHeightTableColumn](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/CellMeasurer/CellMeasurer.DynamicHeightTableColumn.example.js) example and adapt it for my use case. I can see in the [CellMeasurer demo](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/CellMeasurer) that the single-line rows have the default height, defined when initializing the cache. However, in my case, it seems like single-line rows always have the tallest row height, stored in the cache, instead of the default one.

Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Immutable from 'immutable';
import { Table, Column, AutoSizer, CellMeasurer, CellMeasurerCache } from 'react-virtualized';

interface Props {
    logs: Immutable.List<Immutable.Map<string, any>>;
    columns: (
        width: number
    ) => Array<{
        name: string;
        key: string;
        width: number;
        variableHeight?: boolean;
    }>;
}

export default class LogTable extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    private cache: CellMeasurerCache;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
            defaultHeight: 20,
            fixedWidth: true,
            keyMapper: () => 1
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { logs } = this.props;

        return (
            <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                {({ width }) => (
                    <Table
                        headerHeight={20}
                        height={250}
                        rowCount={logs.size}
                        rowHeight={this.cache.rowHeight}
                        width={width}
                        overscanRowCount={2}
                        rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
                        headerClassName='col-header'
                        gridClassName='log-table-grid'
                        rowClassName='log-table-row'
                        className='log-table'
                        rowGetter={({ index }) => logs.get(index)}
                        deferredMeasurementCache={this.cache}>
                        {this.renderColumns(width)}
                    </Table>
                )}
            </AutoSizer>
        );
    }

    private renderColumns(width) {
        return this.props.columns(width).map(({ name, key, width, variableHeight }, idx) => {
            const props: any = {
                label: name,
                dataKey: key,
                width,
                key,
                className: 'column'
            };
            if (variableHeight) {
                props.cellRenderer = this.cellRenderer.bind(this, idx);
            }

            return <Column {...props} />;
        });
    }

    private rowRenderer(params) {
        const { key, className, columns, rowData, style } = params;

        if (!rowData) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div className={className} key={key} style={style}>
                {columns}
            </div>
        );
    }

    private cellRenderer(colIndex, { dataKey, parent, rowIndex }) {
        const content = this.props.logs.get(rowIndex).get(dataKey);

        return (
            <CellMeasurer
                cache={this.cache}
                columnIndex={colIndex}
                key={dataKey}
                parent={parent}
                rowIndex={rowIndex}>
                <div style={{ whiteSpace: 'normal' }} title={content}>
                    {content}
                </div>
            </CellMeasurer>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is the output (see 2nd row in the table that's too tall for its content)
[image: Broken Table row height]

The only styling (less) I have is the following, which I don't think can cause this behavior

```
.log-table {
    font-size: 14px;

    .col-header {
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .log-table-grid {
        outline: none;
        font-family: monospace;
    }

    .log-table-row {
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        padding: 3px;
    }
}
```